# Swift: Detecting Current URL in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I've got a UIWebView that goes to a portal website. While in the portal, all is well as navigation is handled within the site. When a user clicks outside of the portal to an external site, no navigation so the user can't go back to the portal.

What I would like to do is detect the URL every time the UIWebView changes (a new page loads). From there, I can evaluate if I'm outside of the portal or inside and display navigation tools accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can assign to `UIWebView` delegate and track the loading page in the following method:

```
optional func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

`NSURLRequest` have `URL` property